# Search discord channels for prefered posting channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to search through text channels for preferred channels to post in. Here's my code that works now.

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(Guild):
channel_names = ['cool-channel', 'awesome-server', 'chatters-be-chatting']
for ch in channel_names:
    try:
        channel_id = discord.utils.get(Guild.text_channels, name=ch).id
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        #embed stuff
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        break
    except:
        pass
```

The main problem I have is if someone uses emojis or Unicode in the name, it'll pass right over it. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to search key works in channel names regardless of whatever else is in the name.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Why get the id and make it back into a channel if there's already the channel there? Instead of using `get` you could probably iterate through all the channels and use regex/`'string1' in 'string2'` to match them. It's probably a bad idea hardcoding the list though, as I've seen many types of "general" text channels, named really weird things (including `general`, `chat`, `main`, `lounge`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still learning as i go. Basically im after the channel id to save in a database. Anything that looks close enough to where the most likely the owner would want it to post. Even if its "mainchatyo" itll see chat and the bot to guess "well this looks close enough, ill try this till the owner tells me where to post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want to match channel names with keywords you give and then post a message in those channels, a code like this below would do.

I made it a `@bot.command` to test it easily, but I'm sure you can rewrite it to a `@bot.event` without a problem.

```
    @bot.command()
    async def test(ctx):
        keywords = ['cool', 'awesome', 'chatters']  # there you can put your keywords to match with channel names
        text_channel_list = []  # empty list for channel names in the guild
        matches = []  # empty list for channels matching keywords
        for channel in ctx.message.guild.text_channels:
            text_channel_list.append(str(channel))  # adds every channel in the guild to the text_channel_list
        for keyword in keywords:
            for text_channel in text_channel_list:
                if keyword in text_channel:  # looks if keyword is in any channel name
                    matches.append(text_channel) # if there's a match, it adds the matched channel name to matches list
        for match in matches:
            channel_id = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.text_channels, name=match).id
            channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            await channel.send('test')  # prints a test message in every channel from the matches list
```